# Do find() queries with certain fields work faster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say `users` collection contains documents like these:

```
_id: "jsmith",
name: "John Smith",
roles: {"project1": "user", "project2": "admin"}
```

If I only need to query the `name` (and probably `_id`) I can use:

```
db.users.find({_id: "jsmith"}, {name:1})
```

Or I can use projection:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  $match: {_id: "jsmith"},
  $project: {name: 1}
])
```

Does this query work faster then the query without projection? The `roles` property is not loaded at all, correct?

Comment: the biggest benefit is that you don't need to transport data that you're not going to use (in your case, the `roles`). For single document it may be unnoticeable, but for larger sets (imagine reading 1000 documents) differences are significant